# How can i convert a below div into the following form as shown below

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is the table which i have written in foreach loop

```
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Hiring_Manager_ID, new { placeholder = "Hiring Manager ID", @class = "form-input" })</td>
```

and i have added a div container in the next line as follows

```
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Hiring_Manager_ID, new { placeholder = "Hiring Manager ID", @class = "form-input" })</td>
                    <td>
                        
                        <div class="dropdown" asp-for="Status">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" asp-for="Status" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Status
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Yet To Start</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">In Progress</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Completed</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </td>
```

The issue is it's the div block is not getting looped can any one please tell me how to add a=>a[j] for the above div block so it can get looped **Thanks In Advance**

Comment: Please show code of the `View` including the `loop` (foreach or for)